# URL hacking to dynamically change filters for Joined Reports?

Tags: reporting, urlhacking, joined-reports

I'm trying to provide dynamic links to a Joined Report (in this case, the first block is Activities with Contacts, and the second block is Activities with Leads). I have only a single filter in each block, both for the 'Subject' field of the activity object.

If this were a normal, tabular report type, I could just add a `?pv0={!custom_field__c}` (or something like that) to the end of the report URL, stick it in a custom link, and boom, the filter value of the linked report would change based on the value of the custom field.

But with a joined report, that doesn't work! Does anyone know if it's possible to dynamically change filters for individual blocks in a joined report?

Thanks!

Comment: On a regular report, you can use View Page Source to see the pv0 id value. Does Page Source help you on the joined report?

Comment: Anecdotally, I've heard that it isn't possible. I don't know of an official answer about this, though.

Comment: @JeremyNottingham If I view page source on the run report and search for 'pv0' I get no result. When I search for the value I set the filter to, I find a JSON string, eg 
"filters":[{"pc":"SUBJECT","pn":"eq","pv":"totes","pc2":"","cc":false}]

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to do something similar, and found a page that makes this sound possible.
Disclaimer: I have not reproduced this with any success yet, but thought it still may be worth passing along.

The page is located here: http://pawanns-salesforce.blogspot.ca/2013/12/url-hacking-for-cross-join-reports.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, it appears that URL hacking a Joined Report isn't possible based on the information currently around the interwebs. Salesforce's own documentation on URL hacking in general is quite sparse and incomplete.

But if (like me) you were messing with Joined Reports because you wanted to get Contact activities and Lead activities on the same report, I was able to find a better report. Instead of using the "Activities with Contacts" and "Activities with Leads" reports, I used the "Tasks and Events" report. This report shows ALL tasks/events (you can filter to just show activities), regardless of whether they are tied to Contacts or Leads. While you won't be able to access all the contact or lead fields on this report, you will at least see all the activities in one place.